# Не работает функция pow

Tags: c

Пытаюсь скомпилировать программу, но ничего не получается, что не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

struct Dots{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main (){
    struct Dots m = {3 , 5};
    printf("%d\n", pow(m.x, 2));
}
```

вот, что пишет компилятор:

```
/tmp/ccc6T5kG.o: In function `main':
tets.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: -lm во флаги добавили?

Comment: Текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос плиз

Answer (score 1):

Включите предупреждения компилятора!

> ```
> main.c:11:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
> ```

Если заменить `%d` на `%f`, то выводится правильный результат.

---

> заменил, но ошибка не исчезла (undefined reference to `pow')

Текст ошибки нужно было сразу добавить в вопрос.

Значит, вам нужно также добавить `-lm` к флагам линковщика, как подсказывают в комментариях.

Comment: заменил, но ошибка не исчезла (undefined reference to `pow')

Comment: @VladStepanov Значит вам, кроме этого, нужно добавить флаг `-lm`.

Comment: все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @VladStepanov Покажите целиком команду, которой компилируете. Флаг поставили после имени файла с кодом (правильно) или до (неправильно)?

Comment: да, я не правильно поставил флаг